# How Do I bind getCommissions() On ngOnInit() using Observable and map? Currently Returning NULL

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting

I am having trouble getting the commissionData to bind after using the map method on a get request in the component. If I console log the array inside the map method, I get data in the console. But, ngOnInit() -> getCommissions(); returns nothing to the browser just an empty {} when I print it out with:

```
{{ commissions | json }}
```

I am using Observables which I am new to; as I normally subscribe to my service requests, but this is a special requirement for the data I am trying to handle. I've been scratching my head for some time about this and need someone far more capable than I, to show me what I've done wrong.

**My Component TS File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnalyticsService } from '../analytics.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Commission } from '../commission';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-click-cards',
  templateUrl: './click-cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./click-cards.component.scss']
})
export class ClickCardsComponent implements OnInit {

  commissions$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private analyticsService: AnalyticsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCommissions();
  }

  getCommissions(){
    this.commissions$ = this.analyticsService.getAllCommissionData().pipe(
      filter(Boolean),
      map((commissionData: {data: Commission[]}) => {
        const commissions = commissionData.data;//this logs out the array
        return _.uniqBy(commissions.sort((a, b) => b.clicks - a.clicks), commission => commission.page_url);
      }),
      map((commissionData: {data: Commission[]}) => {
        const commissions = commissionData.data;//this logs out the array
        return _.groupBy(commissions, commission => commission.page_type)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="commissions$ | async as commissions">
  <pre>{{ commissions$ }}</pre>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let page_type of ['home', 'article','statistics', 'products']">
    <h4>{{ page_type | titlecase }}</h4>
    <p *ngIf="!commissions[page_type]">No {{ page_type }} Commissions Logged Yet</p>
    <pre>{{ commissions | json }}</pre>
    <ul *ngFor="let card of commissions[page_type]">
      <app-click-card [card]="card"></app-click-card>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I am getting all CommissionData from my service like this, which maps to the data set from the API:

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/app/environments/environments';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Article } from './article';
import { Commission } from './commission';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AnalyticsService {

  article_url = environment.api_url + 'text_image_templates/rows';
  commissions_url = environment.api_url + 'commissions/rows';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllArticles(){
    return this.http.get<{data: Article[]}>(this.article_url)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError),
    );
  }

  getAllCommissionData(): Observable<{data: Commission[]}>{
    return this.http.get<{data: Commission[]}>(this.commissions_url)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError),
    )
  }

  handleError(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error) {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage = error;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

I have been working on this for a while now and I feel like I am pretty close to getting this to work, but getting the data to bind to the browser after ngOnInit() is a real headache. I don't usually work with Observables, so this is new territory for me.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why this is not binding?

Comment: should you not be using `commisions.data.sort`? your types dont match the data returned so they would also need updating

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Commission[]'. error in VS tweaked my class too, but doesn't want to play

Comment: With your service matching the result of the API, you're gonna have the same object coming in your map. You should have the same type ({data: Commission[]} and make the sort over the data property

Comment: @Alex so something like this? 

map((commissions: {data: Commission[]}) => _.uniqBy(data.sort((a, b) => b.clicks - a.clicks), commission => commission.page_url))

I get this in VS: Cannot find name 'data'.

Comment: I would do
```
map((commissionData: {data: Commission[]}) => {
   const commissions = commissionData.data;
   return _.uniqBy(commissions.sort((a, b)=> b.clicks - a.clicks), commision => commission.page_url)
})
})
```

Comment: That's fixed it the error, now to work out why the data isn't binding! Thanks Alex!

Comment: it is probably due to cold observable... do you see a http get for `this.commissions_url` in your "network tab" (in your browser)... you might need to subscribe to your http to solve this

Comment: Hi @Bill, as I understand it, you cant subscribe to an observable? I normally subscribe to my requests, but this one requires an observable in order to sort the array on return